# make part of a line in flextable bold

Tags: r, flextable

I have:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = "this is some text <b>that is bold<\b> this is plain")
```

I want to make the part in the tags **bold** in a flextable. I have 100s of rows of data and specfic bits of text will be made bold.

`df %>% flextable()` returns:

[image]

Any suggestions? Am I missing somehting obvious?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install packages in your environment, using markdown syntax & the `colformat_md` function from ftExtra is probably the simplest way to achieve what you want:

```
library(flextable)
library(ftExtra)
library(dplyr)

# note use of double asterisks to enclose bold text in markdown syntax
df = data.frame(col1 = "this is some text **that is bold** this is plain")

df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  colformat_md()
```

[image: flextable result]

Otherwise you can mess around with the `compose` function from flextable, though unless your input data has very consistent formatting (e.g. each cell's contents can be separated into the same sequence of 'plain text' + 'bold text' + 'plain text'), it may not be worth the trouble.