# In flextable, how can part of a footer be bolded?

Tags: r, flextable

I use flextable extensively when preparing RMarkdown documents. However, I always need to manually bold parts of the footer to follow my company's style guide.

For example, let's say I make the following flextable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

flex_tab <- head(iris) |>
  flextable() |>
  add_footer_row(values = paste0("Source: Fisher, 1936."), colwidths = ncol(df))
```

I would like to be able to specify what part of the footer should be bolded in the code so I could get something like this:

[image]

Note the bolded **Source**, in case it isn't easy to see.

Is there any way I can bold part of the footer in the code?

I did review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630081/make-part-of-a-line-in-flextable-bold), but it didn't seem to apply to my situation and the solution did not work.

Comment: Change values to `values = as_paragraph(as_b("Source:")," Fisher, 1036.")`

Comment: That worked! Would you like to add it as the answer and I'll mark it as such?