# Flextable not rendering bold text

Tags: r, flextable, text-formatting

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630081/make-part-of-a-line-in-flextable-bold) talking about a similar problem I have. I would like to get a table that already contains html tags (`<b></b>`) to set substrings in **bold**. Unfortunately, flextable does not return text in bold, but instead write html tags as plain text.

The solution that was proposed was to use `colformat_md` function from ftExtra. Unfortunately, this takes quite long depending on the number of rows and it relies on bold strings defined by `**`.

Is there another way to render html tags contained in the table when using flextable ? The goal is then to insert the table in a Word document.